# Multiple textfields in iOS Application

Tags: ios, uitextfield, textfield

I have many textfields in an particular view of my iOS application. Some textfields have popover controller while others have textfields that can be typed.

The problem I face is when I touch the textfields. Before I end editing of that particular textfield, if I touch the popovercontroller, both the popovercontroller and textfields appear on the UI.

How to avoid this?

Sorry being vague. Here is the image. I want the texteditor to go off when another textfield is being touched.

[image]

Tried doing this:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSArray *subviews = [self.view subviews];
    for (id objects in subviews) {
        if ([objects isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
            UITextField *theTextField = objects;
            if ([objects isFirstResponder]) {
                [theTextField resignFirstResponder];
            }
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```

not working either... Need some guidance on this...

Tried this as well:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
      NSArray *subviews = [self.view subviews];
        for (id objects in subviews) {
            if ([objects isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
                UITextField *theTextField = objects;
                if ([objects isFirstResponder]) {
                    [theTextField resignFirstResponder];
                }
            }
        }
        return YES;
}
```

Comment: When you touch a textFiled...make all disable. Once you are done with your typing enable all.

Comment: is there a better solution? Because I was looking at resignfirstresponder if popovercontroller textfield was touched...

Comment: how do you implement that?

Comment: UITextField have some differnet delegates, check which one is called when you touch, and which is called when you touch outside. I can't give you code, *no ios knowledge*.

Comment: It is very difficult to understand and visualize what you are describing. Attach a screenshot or sketch to explain.

Comment: edited the question.. have a look..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

Comment: textFieldShouldBeginEditing I guess.

Comment: did this: - (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    return YES;
} not working either...

Comment: correct answer, but put the statement in the action i attached to the textfield.